# Capturing overflow in twos complement addition

Tags: binary, computer-arithmetic

I am trying to implement 8-bit twos complement addition. I am doing this by splitting the 8 bit inputs into 4 bit parts and then implementing 4 bit complement addition.

A well known diagram is
[image]

where V captures the overflow from the addition.

My question: to capture the overflow accurately, does it suffice to capture the overflow at the last steps (final carry and previous carry) in the 8 bit circuit, or do I need to capture the overflow at the last steps in the 4 bit circuit, then somehow combine them in the 8 bit circuit?

Comment: It suffices to capture it at the 8-bit level. You won't require **V** from the lower-order 4-bit section. (Unless you are doing a 4-bit CPU, anyway.) Why would you think otherwise?